# PO Confirmation DevelopmentAX 2012R2

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have added a column/field on POLines Grid. when i am inserting everything is fine.When i am editing the customized column/field 'Confirm button' is still disabled.otherwise if i edit rest of the columns/fields 'Confirm button' is enabled.

I need to enable 'Confirm button' on editing of customized field. Please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in code, you will have to modify the method `isChangeConfirmationRequired` in the map `PurchLineMap` so that it return `true` when your field has been modified.

This will also require you to add a new field to the `PurchlineHistory` table (same type of you new field) and also require mapping the two fields in the `PurchLineMap` map.